# geom_histogram: wrong bins?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot 2.1.0 to plot histograms, and I have an unexpected behaviour concerning the histogram bins.
I put here an example with left-closed bins (i.e. [ 0, 0.1 [ ) with a binwidth of 0.1.

```
mydf <- data.frame(myvar=c(-1,-0.5,-0.4,-0.1,-0.1,0.05,0.1,0.1,0.25,0.5,1))
myplot <- ggplot(mydf, aes(myvar)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..count..),binwidth = 0.1, boundary=0.1,closed="left")
myplot
ggplot_build(myplot)$data[[1]]
```

[image]

On this example, one may expect the value -0.4 to be within the bin [-0.4, -0.3[, but it falls instead (mysteriously) in the bin [-0.5,-0.4[. Same thing for the value -0.1 which falls in [-0.2,-0.1[ instead of [-0.1,0[...etc.

Is there something here I do not fully understand (especially with the new "center" and "boundary" params)? Or is ggplot2 doing weird things there?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Arnaud

PS: Also asked here: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1651

Comment: Probably a consequence of [floating point imprecision](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/1412059). The interval limits are calculated floating point numbers after all.

Comment: That is...unfortunate. However I do not have the same result with ggplot 2.1.0 (http://i66.tinypic.com/1sy2w4.jpg) and ggplot0.9.3 (http://i65.tinypic.com/4rsvev.jpg), which is very disturbing.

Comment: Please note that ggplot 0.9.3 behaves as expected.

Comment: Well...I suppose I have to stay on ggplot version 0.9.3.

Comment: You can always try binning outside of ggplot2.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** The problem described below was fixed in a recent release of `ggplot2`.

Your issue is reproducible and appears to be caused by rounding errors, as suggested in the comments by Roland. At this point, this looks to me like a bug introduced in version `ggplot2_2.0.0`. I speculate below about its origin, but first let me present a workaround based on the `boundary` option.

**PROBLEM**:

```
df <- data.frame(var = seq(-100,100,10)/100)
as.list(df) # check the data
$var
 [1] -1.0 -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2
[10] -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7
[19]  0.8  0.9  1.0
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = var)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), 
        binwidth = 0.1, 
        boundary = 0.1, 
        closed = "left")
p
```

[image]

**SOLUTION**

**Tweak the `boundary` parameter**. In this example, setting just below 1, say 0.99, works. Your use case should be amenable to tweaking too.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = var)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), 
        binwidth = 0.05, 
        boundary = 0.99, 
        closed = "left")
```

(I have made the binwidth narrower for better visual)

[image]

Another workaround is to introduce your own fuzziness, e.g. multiply the data by 1 plus slightly less than the machine zero (see `eps` below). In `ggplot2` the fuzziness multiplies by 1e-7 (earlier versions) or 1e-8 (later versions).

**CAUSE:**

The problem appears clearly in `ncount`:

```
str(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]])
##  'data.frame':   20 obs. of  17 variables:
##   $ y       : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 ...
##   $ count   : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 ...
##   $ x       : num  -0.95 -0.85 -0.75 -0.65 -0.55 -0.45 -0.35 -0.25 -0.15 -0.05 ...
##   $ xmin    : num  -1 -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1 ...
##   $ xmax    : num  -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1 0 ...
##   $ density : num  0.476 0.476 0.476 0.476 0.476 ...
##   $ ncount  : num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 ...
##   $ ndensity: num  1.05 1.05 1.05 1.05 1.05 2.1 1.05 1.05 1.05 0 ...
##   $ PANEL   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##   $ group   : int  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
##   $ ymin    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
##   $ ymax    : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 ...
##   $ colour  : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##   $ fill    : chr  "grey35" "grey35" "grey35" "grey35" ...
##   $ size    : num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
##   $ linetype: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##   $ alpha   : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$ncount
##  [1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.5
## [13] 0.5 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.5
```

**ROUNDING ERRORS?**

Looks like:

```
    df <- data.frame(var = as.integer(seq(-100,100,10)))
# eps <- 1.000000000000001 # on my system
eps <- 1+10*.Machine$double.eps
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = eps*var/100)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), 
                   binwidth = 0.05, 
                   closed = "left")
p
```

(I have removed the `boundary` option altogether)

[image]

This behaviour appears some time after `ggplot2_1.0.1`. Looking at the source code, e.g. `bin.R` and `stat-bin.r` in `https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R`, and tracing the computations of `count` leads to function `bin_vector()`, which contains the following lines:

```
bin_vector <- function(x, bins, weight = NULL, pad = FALSE) {
 ... STUFF HERE I HAVE DELETED FOR CLARITY ...
cut(x, bins$breaks, right = bins$right_closed,
include.lowest = TRUE)
... STUFF HERE I HAVE DELETED FOR CLARITY ...
}
```

By comparing the current versions of these functions with older ones, you should be able to find the reason for the different behaviour...   to be continued...

**SUMMING UP DEBUGGING**

By `"patching"` the `bin_vector` function and printing the output to screen, it appears that:

1. `bins$fuzzy` correctly stores the fuzzy parameters
2. The non-fuzzy `bins$breaks` are used in the computations, but as far as I can see (and correct me if I'm wrong) the `bins$fuzzy` are not.
3. If I simply replace `bins$breaks` with `bins$fuzzy` at the top of `bin_vector`, the correct plot is returned. Not a proof of a bug, but a suggestion that perhaps more could be done to emulate the behaviour of previous versions of `ggplot2`.
4. At the top of `bin_vector` I expected to find a condition upon which to return either `bins$breaks` or `bins$fuzzy`. I think that's missing now.

**PATCHING**

To `"patch"` the `bin_vector` function, copy the function definition from the github source or, more conveniently, from the terminal, with:

```
 ggplot2:::bin_vector
```

Modify it (patch it) and assign it into the namespace:

```
library("ggplot2")
bin_vector <- function (x, bins, weight = NULL, pad = FALSE) 
{
... STUFF HERE I HAVE DELETED FOR CLARITY ...
## MY PATCH: Replace bins$breaks with bins$fuzzy
bin_idx <- cut(x, bins$fuzzy, right = bins$right_closed,
include.lowest = TRUE)
... STUFF HERE I HAVE DELETED FOR CLARITY ...
ggplot2:::bin_out(bin_count, bin_x, bin_widths)
## THIS IS THE PATCHED FUNCTION
}
assignInNamespace("bin_vector", bin_vector, ns = "ggplot2")
df <- data.frame(var = seq(-100,100,10)/100)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = var)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), binwidth = 0.05, boundary = 1, closed = "left")
```

Just to be clear, the code above is edited for clarity: the function has a lot of type-checking and other calculations which I have removed, but which you would need to patch the function. Before you run the patch, restart your R session or `detach` your currently loaded `ggplot2`.

**OLD VERSIONS**

The unexpected behaviour is **NOT** observed in versions `2.0.9.3` or `2.1.0.1` and appears to originate in the current release `2.2.0.1` (or perhaps the earlier `2.2.0.0`, which gave me an error when I tried to call it).

To install and load an old version, say `ggplot2_0.9.3`, create a separate directory (no point in overwriting the current version), say `ggplot2093`:

```
URL <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/ggplot2_0.9.3.tar.gz" 
install.packages(URL, repos = NULL, type = "source", 
    lib = "~/R/testing/ggplot2093")
```

To load the old version, call it from your local directory:

```
library("ggplot2", lib.loc = "~/R/testing/ggplot2093")
```

Comment: Thank you for tracing the problem. You said that the diddle function was removed, but if you look at the bin.R file in the latest version of ggplot (https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/bin.R), I have the impression that the param "fuzz" is replacing "diddle". Is that correct?

Comment: Discussion moved to ``https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1651``. Will report back here if the source of the bug/feature is uncovered.

Comment: Indeed, `bin$fuzzy` does not seem to be used anywhere... I hope Hadley (or anyone competent) will enlighten us on this topic. Anyway, thank you for the patch!